# RO in basement drain

Tags: plumbing

I’m looking to move my RO filter unit from under the sink into the basement during a remodel of our kitchen. The current waste/drain is just hooked in via the standard 1/4 inch drain saddle bracket above the p trap. When moving the RO to the basement it will be directly under the kitchen sink, I’d like to connect to a horizontal PVC drain line that connects to both washing machine and kitchen sink. I’m reading in these kinds of installations it may require an Air gap to avoid contamination if there is a sewer backup etc.
I’m having trouble figuring out what to purchase to accomplish this, and I’m thinking it’s not a good idea to just stick a saddle on one of the main drain lines. Is there a kit to connect a 1/4 RO drain to a drain in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, at the simplest, arrange the pipe so that it sits above a pipe leading to a trap with an air gap between the bottom of the pipe and the top of the pipe below. Typically that's supposed to be 2 pipe diameters, minimum.

Or the same, but use a sink as the way to get to a pipe and trap (mount the pipe above a sink.)

Or, for a different version of "simplest" you can buy an air gap fitting.

In any case you need a trap between the place water goes in and the drain line - "saddle fittings" should only be installed before a trap, if at all. For a horizontal drain line that typically means you'll need to buy a wye fitting and cut it in, then plumb a trap into the arm of the wye.

Or, you can run it into a sump, or floor drain, if there is one, barring local rules saying you can't fo that.

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably just buy something like and plumb it into the wye + trap like you talked about
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EMC06X2